# opengl /es get available render buffer formats

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I write cross platform opengl /es application.
And I want to use Stencil test with FBO. So I need to attach stencil /+depth render buffer storage.

The problem is - some devices does not support `STENCIL_INDEX8`, but support `DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES`. Other devices support only `DEPTH24_STENCIL8`.

So. Is there any way to get list of supported render buffers for particular device?
Or I should just probe all of them with `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` ?

Comment: Those are both extensions in GLES 2.0 _(is that the version you are using?)_ [`GL_OES_stencil8`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_stencil8.txt) (`GL_STENCIL_INDEX8_OES`) and [`GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_packed_depth_stencil.txt) (`GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES`) . Check your extensions string to determine which one of those are available.

Comment: It may be ES and it may be desktop. `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8_OES `- and what about usual `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8` ? I mean, for example, iOS does not support anything but `GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES` beginning from 4th  iPhone. Android, support only `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8` + `GL_DEPTH16` (while it do not have `GL_OES_stencil8` extension) . Some desktop support only STENCIL+DEPTH, another only separate ...

Comment: Which version of ES are you targeting? Because in ES 2.0, `GL_STENCIL_INDEX8` is a [mandatory format](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf#page=127&zoom=auto).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman yes - it's mandatory, but alas it does not work with iPhone4 (doc says to use GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES instead) I judge from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270688/1559666

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8150719/1559666

Comment: Oh, are you talking about a situation where you want ***both*** a stencil buffer and a depth buffer attachment? Generally you have to use a packed format for that, not a lot of implementations let you have separate depth and stencil. You could have an FBO with a depth attachment or an FBO with a stencil attachment, but to get both you would have to use a packed format.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - well, now I need only stencil attachment... 1) But does depth buffer can work without stencil? I mean in depth test mode. 2) And do I have to use packed version (stencil+depth) even on desktop GL [I understand that packed version faster in terms of memory bandwith]?